# Count returning and new customers by day in the last month

Tags: sql, postgresql

There were some similar questions but I didn't get what I needed and I'm not very experienced with complex SQL queries so a little help would be great.

I have two tables. Customers and Sales_history.

Customers schema:

```
id | ... (rest doesn't matter)
```

Sales_history schema:

```
id | customer_id | date ...
```

What I need is to get, by day, the amount of return and new customers in the last month for example.

An array/JSON of the following sort:

```
days: [
    0: {
        date: '23-09-2016',
        returns: 23,
        new: 10
    },
    1: {
        date: '22-09-2016',
        returns: 13,
        new: 4
    }
    ]
```

I tried several queries with answers I researched but the format wasn't right and didn't account for same day sales.

Comment: how would you define return and new customers?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried to avoid answers that didn't work out for you.

Comment: Return customers are customers who have at least one sale registered in sales_history. If two sales in the same day occur there is no need to account the customer as return in the second sale. New customers are customers who have 1 sale only registered. I analized the DB and it's actually more complex than this. We'll have to review this. I'll delete the question, but upvote your comments. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Nevermind the deleting part. I'll leave it open and see if anything comes up that helps. Thank you.